# Area51 site says "no user found" if I press register button

Tags: bug, profile-page, area-51, user-accounts, sign-up

I have create an account from "sign up" button in the Area51 site but when I try to connect me to Area51 site it says "No user found".

I have followed a topic that interest me and seems it have create an account with my email an connect me to my network profile but if I press button register, the Area51 site give me the same message.

Another issue is about the network profile update from another StackExchange profile: seems doesn't work (my network profile image doesn't update).

Comment: Have you tried creating a new account for Area51 on your old e-mail address? I recall this is an old problem, your question is probably already asked before.

Comment: @Mast before create a new account I have asked for recovery my password in the login form and I have received a mail that says my email address doesn't exist in the StackExchange db. After that I have used the signup form in the Area51 site.
My timeline (more o less) on the site was: 
 - check if exist an account
 - mail says to me the my email address doesn't exist in the Stackexchange db
 - signup on Area51
 - confirm my email address
 - check login on Area51 site
 - No user found error messagge
 - follow topic on Area51 site

Comment: I have this same issue. Havn't tried recovering my password though. All other sites work